# Selenium does not see alert window

Tags: java, selenium

I have a random fails in my selenium tests. I am testing an alert window in place, but seems that randomly selenium tests does ignore somehow the alert window. what is the problem? Please help.

I am using the following code

```
public String checkAlert() {

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    String txt = alert.getText();
    alert.dismiss();

    return txt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this "customized" wait handler :

```
public static String waitJSResponse(WebDriver driver, String script) {
        String ReturnedValue = null;
        int sleeper = 10;
        Boolean flag = false;
        int timeOut = 30000;
        int i = 0;
        while ((!flag) & ((i*sleeper)<timeOut)) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleeper);
                ReturnedValue = (String) driver.executeScript(script);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                flag = false;
                i++;
            }
            if (ReturnedValue != null) {
                flag = true;
                System.out.println("Overall response time : "+(i * sleeper)+" ms \n\r");
                break;
            }
        }
        return ReturnedValue;
    }
```

In your script (as a String) use the following code :

```
function getAlert() {

  var elem = document.scripts;
  for (var i = 0, len = elem.length; i < len; i++) {

    var txt = elem[i].textContent.match(/alert\(['"]([^'"]+)['"]\)/);
    if (txt) { return txt[1]; }
  }
}
```